# Error itext wont generate a pdf file

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

I downloaded `itextpdf-5.1.0.jar` and already enabled `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` on `AndroidManifest.xml` and i just started on `itext` and try some tutorials on it but, for some reason i can't generate a pdf.

Anyone know what's wrong with this code?

```
import android.os.Environment;

import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class MainActivity{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Document document = new Document();

    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Paragraph.pdf"));

        document.open();
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk(
                    "This is a sentence which is long " + i + ". ");
            paragraph.add(chunk);
        }

        document.add(paragraph);
        document.close();

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Any Exceptions/Error Logs?

Comment: itextpdf is for Java. If you want to use iText on Android, you need to use the Android port [iTextG](http://itextpdf.com/itextg-android). The difference? iText uses classes that aren't whitelisted on Android/GAE (`java.awt.*`, `javax.nio.*`) and this causes errors on Android. iTextG is a version of iText that doesn't depend on those classes.

Comment: Thank you sir. I think I made a big mistake on understanding in Itext

Comment: @BrunoLowagie One question sir, is ItextG have the same concept and code on iText? Thank you

Comment: Yes. It's the same code, with only AWT and some other stuff removed because it isn't available on Android.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thank you

Comment: One more thing. We just released itextpdf and itextg 5.5.8 a couple of days ago.